# Get client ip with python

Tags: python, apache, webserver, mod-python

I'm a newbie in python.
I want to write a simple web that prints the client ip on screen

my http.conf Handler:
    AddHandler mod_python .py
    PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
    PythonDebug On

The cgi.escape(os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]) return this error: KeyError: 'REMOTE_ADDR'
and I just get lost with the BaseHTTPRequestHandler
so what is the simple way to get the client ip?
thank you.

Answer (score 7):

In case you're concerned about scalability, this might be a bit faster:

```
from mod_python import apache
req.get_remote_host(apache.REMOTE_NOLOOKUP)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer:

```
from mod_python import apache
def client_ip(req):
    req.add_common_vars()
    return req.subprocess_env['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

It's working!